# how to get id of the table column when clicked on image in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

When someone clicks the image, I want to get the id of the column where the image is stored in the mysql database and use it to show other data in a different div. But i dont know how to do that.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$blog= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blog");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($blog)):
$id=$row['blog_id'];
$tit=$row['title'];
$img=$row['image'];
$cont=$row['content'];

?>

    <div id="all_blog">
   <img src="<?php echo $img ?>"  height="150" width="200" id="blog_img"/>
    </div>

    <?
endwhile;   
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to write that id into somewhere, either in img tag, or div tag.

```
<?php
$blog= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blog");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($blog)):
$id=$row['blog_id'];
$tit=$row['title'];
$img=$row['image'];
$cont=$row['content'];
?>

<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
   <img src="<?php echo $img ?>"  height="150" width="200" id="blog_img" class="blogImage" />
</div>

<?
endwhile;   
?>
```

Then you take that id with jquery

```
<script>
$(".blogImage").click(function() {
    var blogId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    // then do something with that id
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting data() method  of jquery to image tag   ->[see here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

return this from server side along with image tag

```
 $('selector').data('col_name','xyz');
```